# How the member's initial value like 'contents(ht * wd, c)' works in constructor function in C++ Primer?

Tags: c++, constructor, member-initialization

I have read the book C++ Primer. In section 7.3.1: there is a constructor of `Screen` class:

```
class Screen {
public:
    typedef std::string::size_type pos;
    Screen() = default; 
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c): height(ht), width(wd),
                                     contents(ht * wd, c) { }
    char get() const { return contents[cursor]; } 
    inline char get(pos ht, pos wd) const;
    Screen &move(pos r, pos c);
private:
    pos cursor = 0;
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    std::string contents;
};
```

And in the overloaded constructor function:

```
Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c): height(ht), width(wd),
                                 contents(ht * wd, c) { }
```

What is the initial value of `contents(ht * wd, c)` and how it works?
In the section 7.1.4, there states:

> The constructor initializer is a list of member names, each of which is followed by that member’s initial value in parentheses (or inside curly
>   braces).

And I have known that `string` has a way `string s(n, 'c')` to initialize a string such as `string s(10, 'c')`.
But how it works to utilize the `string` constructor in the constructor member initialization?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's initializing `contents` by calling the constructor as `std::string::string(ht * wd, c)`.

Comment: @songyuanyao, but what about other member initialization? If it is a built-in type, how it works?

Comment: Just as the quotes said, `height` is initialized with the initial value `ht`, `width` is initialized with the initial value `wd`.

Comment: What I want to know is that why it will call the `string` constructor? According to my limited knowledge, I can't image that it will call the `string` constructor automatically. And in any other language like Javascript, there is no way to call function in constructor like this. @songyuanyao.

Comment: That's the way you initialize an object with class type in C++, almost always the constructor of the class type will be invoked, member initializer list is just one of these ways. BTW: If you don't specify it in the member initializer list, `contents` will be initialized by the default constructor of `std::string`.

Comment: @songyuanyao. Thank you. But there is no introduction about this in the book C++ Primer. So I am confused. Is there any material about this?

Comment: I think these things must be explained somewhere in the book. You can refer to [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for more infos about member initializer list.

Comment: @songyuanyao. Thank you very much.

Comment: i found this sentence after 4-5 pages after the code(shown above) " When we initialize a member of class type, we are supplying arguments to a
constructor of that member’s type" in the book

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter this problem when reading about this. As indicated by songyuanyao, my guessing is that when we use parenthesis or curly braces in the constructor list, the corresponding constructor of each class data member is automatically called by the compiler to initialize the function parameters. For example, in

```
Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c): height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) { }
```

The function parameter `height`, of type `int`, is initialized with `int(ht)`;
The function parameter `width`, of type `int`, is initialized with `int(wd)`;
The function parameter `contents`, of type `std::string`, is initialized with `std::string(ht * wd, c)`;

Feel free to tell me if my answer is not right.

PS: Thanks to @M.M for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Initialization is different to assignment. The arguments go to the constructor of the class member. It doesn't construct a temporary as in your example and then assign that to your default-constructed class member.